# woocommerce cart page display products order by product price

Tags: wordpress, shopping-cart, woocommerce

I have develop shoping cart in wordpress using Woocommerce plugin. I need to display products in the cart order by product price please help me to do this

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To order products low to high or high to low price in the Woocommerce cart, try adding the following to your functions.php file (or plugin):

```
function 12345_cart_updated() {

    $products_in_cart = array();
    // Assign each product's price to its cart item key (to be used again later)
    foreach ( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $item ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );
        $products_in_cart[ $key ] = $product->get_price();
    }

    // SORTING - use one or the other two following lines:
    asort( $products_in_cart ); // sort low to high
    // arsort( $products_in_cart ); // sort high to low

    // Put sorted items back in cart
    $cart_contents = array();
    foreach ( $products_in_cart as $cart_key => $price ) {
       $cart_contents[ $cart_key ] = WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_key ];
    }

    WC()->cart->cart_contents = $cart_contents;

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', '12345_cart_updated' );
```

This function is similar and derived from one seen at https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-sort-cart-items-alphabetically-az/ which is nearly identical to this earlier-posted function: https://gist.github.com/maxrice/6541634

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, for manipulating data on the WordPress ecosystem, the answer will be `wp filter`, no `wp action`.

In addition, `WC_car.cart_contents` array, hold the product object it's self on `$cart_contents['data']; //WC_Product_Object`, So we didn't need to get product again.

### Simple filter to order by price:

PHP 7.4+

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_contents', 'prefix_cart_items_order' );
function prefix_cart_items_order( $cart_contents ) {
  uasort($cart_contents, 
         fn($a, $b) => 
             $a['data']->get_price() < $b['data']->get_price() ? -1 : 1
  );
  return $cart_contents;
}
```

PHP < 7

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_contents', 'prefix_cart_items_order' );
function prefix_cmp ($a, $b) { 
  return $a['data']->get_price() < $b['data']->get_price() ? -1 : 1;
}
function prefix_cart_items_order( $cart_contents ) {
  uasort($cart_contents, 'prefix_cmp');
  return $cart_contents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mmmm, Is right there on the Woo admin page!!

Woocommerce - > Adjustments - > Catalogue - > Default Products Ordering

Comment: How about specifically in the cart/checkout page? This might work: https://gist.github.com/maxrice/6541634